# Pygame music queue

Tags: python, audio, pygame, midi

So this is a question that may not have a nice answer.  Basically I would like to know if it is possible to use the queue in pygame.mixer.music to play multiple tracks immediately one after another.  I have some midi files that I would like to concatenate, as it were, but there is an ugly 0.1s or so gap between them when I use pygame.mixer.music.queue

```
def play_music():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(playLs.get(0))
    for i in playLs.get(0,END):
        print i
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(i)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
```

The playLs is a Tk listbox which has the names of the files I would like to play.  This plays the songs fine, but there is a small gap between each which I would like to know if I can eradicate.  This has shown itself not only with mid files but also wavs, and so I think it might be something in the library, and not the "padding" that might be in the sound file.

Comment: Have you done anything to verify that there isn't padding in your sound files?  You mention that you don't think it is, but don't offer any evidence.

Comment: Wish I knew a solution for this -- I can confirm that I've had the same problem sending consecutive midi files to Pygame and haven't been able to solve it yet.

Comment: Haz: I cannot, but I am reasonably sure that there is not.  It is generated from a midi library that should work.  At the moment I am reduced to having a "compile" option that collates them all together and then just plays the result.  Less than optimal :(

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to use pygame.music.Channel, having both the current and the next song loaded into memory, but different channels?